# Convert Quarter + Year (Datetime) into String in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have some datetime info extracted into columns in Pandas. For example, I got the quarters like this:

```
df['quarter'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ddate'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce').dt.quarter
```

I need to take the 'quarter' and 'year' columns and combine them into something like "Q3_2017". I can get this to work fine with a single data point like this:

```
'Q' + str(df['quarter'].iloc[0]) + '_' + str(df['year'].iloc[0])
```

But when I try to apply "str()" to a whole column I get bizarre results. For instance:

```
df['period'] = str(df['quarter'])
```

Instead of getting the quarter (e.g. "1"), I get something like this:

```
7222 1\n185579 4\n185580 1\n2129..
```

What exactly is going on and what's an easy fix?

I found a few previous solutions, but none seem to work specifically with quarters; can only find out how to do this with month or year, for example.

Comment: What does your input data look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
df['period'] = 'Q' + df['quarter'].astype(str) + '_' + df['year'].astype(str)
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks again for your help! Even after using Pandas for 2 years, some of this syntax still gives me nightmares.

Answer (score 3):

With `Period`s you can access `%q` for strftime.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ddate': pd.date_range('2010-01-01', freq='57D', periods=4)})

df.ddate.dt.to_period('Q').dt.strftime('Q%q_%Y')
0    Q1_2010
1    Q1_2010
2    Q2_2010
3    Q2_2010
Name: ddate, dtype: object
```

---

Or just keep the format of `to_period` (convert to string if you want)

```
df.ddate.dt.to_period("Q")
0    2010Q1
1    2010Q1
2    2010Q2
3    2010Q2
Name: ddate, dtype: period[Q-DEC]
```